# Htaccess redirect the file accessing from one folder to another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal-8

I have pointed out the robots.txt file in the web folder but with some technical or cache issues, it will not be reflected. so we need to point it out in a different location.
For example

```
/var/www/html/web/robots.txt
/var/www/html/web/sites/robots.txt
```

But we should point to the Same URL like this "www.example.com/robots.txt"

Comment: So you want to redirect `www.example.com/robots.txt` to `/var/www/html/web/robots.txt` ?

Comment: No, I want to redirect the URL  "www.example.com/robots.txt" from this file location "/var/www/html/web/robots.txt"  to this location "/var/www/html/web/sites/robots.txt"

Comment: What is your current `DocumentRoot` directory and show your current .htaccess

Comment: we do not add it as of now. we make it after that

Comment: @vigneshrajkumar, where is your htaccess file present? In `/var/www/html` path? Also as stated by anubava sir please do share your htaccess file in your question for clarity of your question, thank you.

Comment: If you need help please show what you already have